# Slick slider + Javascript: Works on inital page load, but not on subsequent page loads without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am using slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) on a page. The javascript that initializes slickslider is included in every page.

The first time the page loads, the slider works perfectly. However, when I click on a link and go to another page, the slider doesn't work or, doesn't get "re-initialized." To get it to work, I have to refresh the page.

This is the javascript block that initializes the slider. I've tried both $(document).ready() and $(window).load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Hi");
  $('.slides').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2500,
      speed: 500,
  });
});
```

It seems that when I go the the next page, the slider is not initialized again because it was already initialized in the current browser "session." JavaScript is not my first language, so I may be missing some fundamentals here.

How can I get it to work so that slider works on each page without the need to refresh the page?

thanks,

Comment: I have the absolutely same issue --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463023/how-to-fix-slick-slider-slick-js-if-it-breaks-on-click-event-within-the-div Following!